# RaySession theming goes crazy if I press the canvas

Tags: kde, themes, qt

I'm facing a problem I have no idea how could I tackle. My main concern is with RaySession, which opens fine, but if I press the wrong place (the canvas), the theming goes crazy, and I'm not able to work anymore, so I have to close the session, close the app and start over.

I'm also having problems with Spotube, which shows just the borders, but I'm not able to see the app, and what's behind it still moves.

I believe it has to do with the fact that I'm using Ubuntu Studio, so I have KDE Plasma. Maybe something with Qt?

There are other apps which I can use but have a weird theming, like Syncthing, which was showing before a consistent theming but at some point it changed.

Output of `neofetch`

```
OS: Kubuntu 23.04 x86_64 
Host: 82EY IdeaPad Gaming 3 15ARH05 
Kernel: 6.2.0-1015-lowlatency 
Uptime: 1 hour, 33 mins 
Packages: 4119 (dpkg), 40 (flatpak), 29 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.2.15 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 5.27.4 
WM: kwin 
WM Theme: Silvery-Blur-Dark-Aurorae 
Theme: [Plasma], Layan [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Papirus-Colors-Dark [Plasma], Papirus-Colors-Dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 4800H with Radeon Graphics (16) @ 2.900GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Renoir 
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile 
Memory: 7401MiB / 15346MiB
```

Output of `qmake --version`

```
QMake version 3.1
Using Qt version 5.15.8 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Screenshot of RaySession gone wrong:
[image]

Screenshot of Spotube:
[image]

Screenshot of Syncthing:
[image]